# Insert a line in a file based on pattern

Tags: shell, sed

I want to insert the new line in a file using sed command

```
sed -i  "/pattern to match/i\ new string to insert" etc/dir.txt
```

This command insert a new line like this, I want to insert the line with the leading spaces in the previous line.

the pattern should be: eod_clusterName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_DC
The line should nsert before or after the pattern line, not the EOF.

```
earFileName: DEV_WAS_eBBS_CN_APP.ear
    eod_appName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_APP
    eod_clusterName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_DC
new string to insert
```

I want to insert new line like, It should automatically follow the leading spaces in the pattern and insert the new line in the file like below

```
earFileName: DEV_WAS_eBBS_CN_APP.ear
    eod_appName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_APP
    eod_clusterName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_DC
    #new string to insert#
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, is it always going to be last line of your file? Or what is the pattern to find (is it a string or line number) where you want to insert new line? Please do add these details in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `i` command can't do that. But you can insert a new line using `s` as well, capturing leading blanks in the current line, and preceding the new line with them. E.g:

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\).*pattern to match.*/&\n\1new string to insert/' file
```

Examples:

```
$ sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\).*clusterName.*/&\n\1new string to insert/' file
earFileName: DEV_WAS_eBBS_CN_APP.ear
    eod_appName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_APP
    eod_clusterName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_DC
    new string to insert
$
$ sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\).*DEV.*/&\n\1new string to insert/' file
earFileName: DEV_WAS_eBBS_CN_APP.ear
new string to insert
    eod_appName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_APP
    new string to insert
    eod_clusterName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_DC
    new string to insert
```

Comment: I am trying to do this by using the variables for pattern and new string also with in place option it is not working can you help me on that.                                       
 sed -i 's/^\([[:space:]]*\).$pattern/&\n\$new/' $path

Comment: @yugendran variable references won't be expanded between single-quotes. `sed -i 's/^\([[:space:]]*\).*'"$pattern"'.*/&\n\1'"$new"'/' "$path"` should work in your case.

Comment: Yes, Sorry I didnt noticed that later realized and tried its working. Thak you for you patience.

Comment: I am not able to insert clusdetails_path:"/apps/support/dump/WSAD/RCB/clusdetails/"  in the place of new in command                                                                                             sed -i 's/^\([[:space:]]*\).*'"$pattern"'.*/&\n\1'"$new"'/' "$path"                          getting an error sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'                  could you please help me on this

Comment: it contains slashes, what were you expecting? replace slashes in the sed script with something else, like `s#...#...#`. This is my last comment

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/eod_clusterName: DEV_WAS_eBBSEOD_CN_DC/{p;s/\S.*/new string to insert/}' file
```

Focus on the line in question, print it and then replace it from the first non-whitespace character to the end of the line with the replacement text.